# Center ImageView in Relative Layout

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have an image and a textview inside a relative layout. The image and the textview take up 50% of the screen width. How can I center the image and the textview ? I have tried many methods and I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Here is my code:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewEventImage"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/eventNameBackground"
                android:id="@+id/textViewEventName"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want your image to be center of screen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Try this code it will suits your requirement**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#ff0000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/americanexpress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Your product" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#00ff00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try like this

Put `imageview` as

```
centerinparent ="true"
```

And `textview` also `centerinparent="true"`

And add one attribute to `textview` 
As

```
android: layout_below="@+id/imageview id"
```

Comment: Thats doesnt work.. The imageview is still on the left side of the screen and the textview is in the middle of the imageview..

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="xxxdp"
        android:layout_height="xxxdp"
        android:src="@drawable/someimage"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="xxxdp"
        android:layout_height="xxxdp" 
        android:text="fweqf"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have to use the relative layout because I want to display the text over the imageview...

Comment: My ans will produce the result as the image you referred which is using a RelativeLayout containing a view which is a  LinearLayout. And what do you mean by "text over the imageview" anyway? do you want your image to look like as your text background? I'd love to know a little more about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ImageView and TextView in the center, then use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textViewEventImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewEventName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewEventImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="There is Your Text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```